# Are gerund clauses, participle clauses, and infinitive clauses all non-finite clauses?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

For instance,

> **"Eating apples without washing"**

Which is a gerund clause, can also function as a non-finite clause, since it has a non-finite verb and its object?

Comment: The category of 'non-finite clauses' consists of gerund-participials, infinitivals and past-participials. Whether or not the non-finite clause contains an object is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, it *is* a non-finite clause, since it contains a verb with no tense and an object. There are different types of non-finite clauses:
[finite and non-finite clauses](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/clauses-finite-and-non-finite)

Comment: I integrated a comment from BillJ since he is saying the same thing

Comment: It's not quite the same thing. As far as I understand, a gerund by itself doesn't constitute a clause.

Comment: For example, 1. *Thinking is the best way to travel.* 2. *Thinking hard is the best way to travel.* 3. *Thinking about other places is the best way to travel.*  To me, only 3, with an object, is clearly a clause. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The category of 'non-finite clauses' consists of gerund-participials, infinitivals and past-participials. Whether or not the non-finite clause contains an object is irrelevant.

Comment: Comment converted to answer.